# Invoice has already paid error message

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, kentico

I am getting below error message after clicking on pay button. I am using sandbox account for payment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are passing an invoice id ( 2142 ) which has been already used for a completed payment. You will need to pass unique invoice id for resolving this issue. Otherwise, you may change the settings in PayPal account in PayPal account under payment receiving preferences as allow duplicate invoice id payment.